# Zend Framework 2 - ZFCUser - Translate login form

Tags: php, authentication, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I'm using `ZFCUser` and need to develop a German project.

Unfortunately the login form is in English and I couldn't find a way to translate the form fields or especially the error messages to English.

Is there maybe a global way for the module to either overwrite the messages or switch the language?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

This is my translator call in my bootstrap:

```
$translator = new Translator();
    $translator->addTranslationFile(
        'phpArray',
        'vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages/de/Zend_Validate.php',
        'default',
        'de_DE'
    );
    AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
```

**Edit II:**

My custom translation file:

```
<?php

return array(

    // ZFCUser
    "Authentication failed. Please try again." => "test"

);
```

My factory:

```
<?php

class CustomTranslatorFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $sl)
    {
        $translator = new Translator();
        $translator->addTranslationFile(
            'phpArray',
            'vendor/.../TranslationTable.php',
            'default',
            'de_DE'
        );
        return $translator;
    }
}
```

Module.php from my User module:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Path\To\Translator\CustomTranslatorFactory',
        ),
    );
}
```

**Edit III:**

My Translator looks like this. Even when using a PHP file instead of the array just nothing happens. No error, no translation. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
    $custom_translations = array(
        "Authentication failed. Please try again." => "test",

    );

    $translator = new Translator();
    $translator->addTranslationFile(
        'phpArray',
        'vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages/de/Zend_Validate.php',
        'default',
        'de_DE'
    );
    $translator->addTranslationFile(
        'phpArray',
        $custom_translations
    );
    return $translator;
```

Comment: I don't know the zfcuser module, but if it uses the default Form View Helpers, labels are translated automatically. However, you'll have to set up the [translator](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.i18n.translating.html) first if not done already. // Edit: Just checked it, yup, it uses the Form View Helpers.

Comment: You have to assign the translator to the view helper (`setTranslator()` method). This is done automatically for you by the `ViewHelperManager` if you register a "translator" service (e.g. put your code from the question into a factory class and register this factory to SM as "translator").

Comment: i should add that all other error messages are translated correctly. so i cant do it terribly wrong, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for Your knowledge - since yesterday there's a modular de_DE translation available (pl_PL and ja_JP are available too). It covers only `ZfcUser` messages, so not all validators, but form labels etc. https://github.com/websafe/zf-mod-zfc-user-i18n-de-de Easy installable and available via Packagist too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm creating an answer for that because it's becoming too complex for the comment section.

The validator library does translation of messages on its own. As you've assigned the translator to it, your validation messages are fine.

However, form label translation belongs to another piece of library. Accordingly, they also need a translator assigned to them. As stated above in the comments, you can either do that manually (by invoking `$viewHelper->setTranslator($translator)`) or let the ViewHelperManager do that for you.

You can easily refactor your code to support the second case.

1. Create a factory class for your translator.
2. Register that factory to SM. Use the "translator" key.
3. If you need it, retrieve your `$translation` var through SM in future.

Example (`use`s skipped):

```
/** One of your modules, should be a base module that's always loaded */
class Module
{

    // ...

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'translator' => 'Your\Translator\Factory', // could also be a closure (anonymous function)
            )
        );
    }
}
```

-

```
class YourTranslatorFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $sl)
    {
        $translator = new Translator();
        $translator->addTranslationFile(
            'phpArray',
            'vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages/de/Zend_Validate.php',
            'default',
            'de_DE'
        );
        return $translator;
    }
}
```

If you need to access it, simpyl retrieve it from SM as you're used to (`$translator = $sm->get('translator');`).

Note: Validators implement the `TranslatorAwareInterface`. This means that, if you've registered the `translator` key to SM, they also should be injected into the validators automatically. Thus, you can even skip the static method call.

Note also: This is just an example of how you can do it without changing much. You could also reach this goal just by configuration.

Comment: thanks for your answer! can i also handle my not-german login error messages with this solution?

Comment: If you configure the translator to handle these languages, yes. You'll have to assign the current language to the translator somewhere, however.

Comment: i cant get it to work. but anyway how should it work, the needed translations aren't part of the standard `Zend_Validate.php`!

Comment: Add another translationFile with the specific error-keys you need the messages for.

Comment: updated my post, again. no error but still not working... any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, if it can wait 4 weeks, I can have a look at it personally after having moved to Cologne ;-) Seriously: The domain and language keys are missing in your code ('default', 'de_DE') after the language file.